# ASP.NET WebApi cannot work with COM (Excel) in Azure

Tags: c#, excel, azure, asp.net-web-api, com

have some problem with COM objects

I have a web api controller that creates and saves Excel file.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

            excel.Workbooks.Add();

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet workSheet = excel.ActiveSheet;

            try
            {

                workSheet.Cells[1, "A"] = "Id";
               -//- 
                int row = 2; 
                foreach (var _c in db.Clients)
                {
                    workSheet.Cells[row, "A"] = _c.ClientId;
                    -//-                     

                    row++;
                }

                        workSheet.Range["A1"].AutoFormat(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlRangeAutoFormat.xlRangeAutoFormatClassic1);

                fileName = string.Format(@"{0}/ExcelData.xlsx", System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Reports"));

               workSheet.SaveAs(fileName);
```

After creation the controller return a url for this file.
On my localHost it works excelent, but after deploying to Azure cloud as a host, I have an exception:

ExceptionMessage :

```
"Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))."
ExceptionType:
"System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException"
Message:
"An error has occurred."
StackTrace:
"   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
```

and etc.

I already try to switch between x64 and x86 - it didn`t help

If somebody know how to fix that trouble, tell me

Comment: Excel won't be installed in your Azure service so don't try to use interop. It is much easier to use [something like ClosedXML](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml)

Comment: Did you deploy as a Web App? VM? Cloud Service (web/worker roles)?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem than you. I found a official statement of Microsoft:

"**Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**"

You will see with the details: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757

I found this solution in a blog

https://debugmode.net/2011/08/28/creating-and-updating-excel-file-in-windows-azure-web-role-using-open-xml-sdk/